# Problem of encoding when sending POST request using Wininet in C++

Tags: php, c++, post, utf-8, wininet

I would like to send UTF-8 content in a POST request with Wininet.
The content is correctly sent but, when it's a special char like `€` is not writed and printed correctly.

I have the same problem with Postman so I don't know very well if it's my PHP code to write the content receveied or if it's my C++ code.
This is the PHP code which write the content in a text file to test the recevie function :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
                $fh = fopen("amount_test.txt", 'w') or die("can't open file");
                fwrite($fh, utf8_encode($_POST["amount"]));
                fclose($fh);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the function to send POST request with UTF-8 content :

```
void sendAmount()
{
    LPCWSTR browser = L"Game/2.3";
    LPCWSTR domain = L"127.0.0.1";
    LPCWSTR methode = L"POST";
    LPCWSTR page = L"/minigame/engine/sendAmount.php";
    std::wstring strContentType = L"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
    LPCWSTR contentType = strContentType.c_str();
    std::string dataStr = "amount=" + "42,342€";
    LPVOID dataToSend = (LPVOID)dataStr.c_str();

    HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpenW(browser, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET hConnection = InternetConnectW(hInternet, domaine, 80, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    HINTERNET hRequest  = HttpOpenRequestW(hConnection, methode, page, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 1);
    HttpSendRequestW(hRequest, contentType, strContentType.size(), dataToSend, dataStr.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every string is `wchar` except:

```
std::string dataStr = "amount=" + "42,342€";
```

should be:

```
std::wstring dataStr = L"amount=" + L"42,342€";
```